# UIViewControllerRepresentable - "Protocol cannot be satisfied by a non-final class" - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Not sure if I'm missing something or found a SwiftUI bug. This is such a simple thing and it's driving me crazy.

Trying to setup a UIViewControllerRepresentable but getting the following errors:

> Protocol 'View' requirement '_makeView(view:inputs:)' cannot be satisfied by a non-final class ('VideoAnswerWrapper') because it uses 'Self' in a non-parameter, non-result type position
>
> Protocol 'View' requirement '_makeViewList(view:inputs:)' cannot be satisfied by a non-final class ('VideoAnswerWrapper') because it uses 'Self' in a non-parameter, non-result type position

[image: Error I'm Seeing]

I've tried:

- Switching the 'VideoAnswerViewController' for
  'VideoAnswerWrapper.UIViewControllerType'
- Restarting Xcode, clearing caches, derived data, etc.
- Starting with a blank ViewController to ensure it's not a weird
  storyboard issue
- Switching down an Xcode version as well as trying the 11.4 beta.
- Different ways of instantiating the VideoAnswerViewController
- Adding 'final' to the class

Here is my UIViewControllerRepresentable class:

```
import SwiftUI

class VideoAnswerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = VideoAnswerViewController

    private var question : Question!


    init(question: Question?) {
        guard let question = question else {fatalError()}
        self.question = question
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoAnswerWrapper>) -> VideoAnswerViewController {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "VideoAnswer", bundle: .main)

        //Downcast returned controller to the requried type
        guard let viewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController() as? VideoAnswerViewController else { fatalError() }

        //Assign selected question object to instance property on incoming viewController.
//        viewController.question = question

        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: VideoAnswerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<VideoAnswerWrapper>) {
        
    }
}
```

UIViewController (I've stripped all the functionality to isolate the bug)

```
import UIKit

class VideoAnswerViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

Comment: If I paste your code into a playground and change one line to `final class VideoAnswerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {` the errors go away.  Are you sure adding "final" didn't at least *change* the errors?

Comment: @PhillipMills ......I'm speechless. I've tried making VideoAnswerViewController final but not the wrapper class. I've been stuck on this for several hours. Thank you!

If you want the credit, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: It's OK.  I *assumed* the complaints were about `VideoAnswerWrapper` because the errors were about the protocol that it adopts.  It's not like I knew for sure.  :)

Comment: @PhillipMills Worth answering, as being likely to arise for others, surely.

Comment: typically the UIViewControllerRepresentable and UIViewController should be struct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ```
> class VideoAnswerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
>
>     typealias UIViewControllerType = VideoAnswerViewController
> ```

The above intended to present a SwiftUI `View` so MUST be a struct as below

```
struct VideoAnswerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewControllerType = VideoAnswerViewController
```